# Instagram EndPoints : Return Blank Data or Showing OAuthException

Tags: android, rest, api, instagram, instagram-api

Good Day !
I am developing an app in android and I need to fetch all the public feed from Instagram, but I am receiving blank data for some API calls and OAuthExceptions for other calls.
My App is Still in `SANDBOX MODE`

This is my token url and access url

```
mTokenUrl = TOKEN_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret="
            + clientSecret + "&redirect_uri=" + mCallbackUrl + "&grant_type=authorization_code";

mAuthUrl = AUTH_URL + "?client_id=" + clientId + "&redirect_uri="
            + mCallbackUrl + "&response_type=code&display=touch&scope=basic+likes+comments+relationships+public_content+follower_list";
```

I am giving all the permissions in `Scope` also. I think Instagram doesn't provide any scope permissions for sandbox users.
Any Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sandbox mode, it will only return users that are in your approved sandbox user list.

Add one of the user you follow to the sandbox and it will show up in the API response.

Comment: Yes! After adding other user as sandbox users, API call is working.
Thanks